# I want to copy a directory from one place to another via the command line

Tags: command-line, sudo

I want to copy a directory from one place to another folder.

`sudo cp` is the command, but after that what should I type? The destination or source first?

Comment: Does `man cp` help?

Answer (score 208):

The `-a` flag is probably what you are looking for:

```
cp -a /path/from /path/to
```

The `-a` flag turns on recursive behaviour (which can also be done with the `-R` flag), and will also attempt to preserve metadata such as file ownership, permissions, timestamps, links, etc.

You should only need to use `sudo` if you are copying to a location not owned by the current user, if the current user doesn't have read permissions for the files being copied, or if you want to preserve ownership on files not owned by the current user.

Comment: in addition, as a rule of thumb, its always like that `[command] [source] [destination]`. This applies to `mv`, `cp`, `ren`.

Comment: @VineetMenon You probably mean `mv`, not `ren`.

Comment: @jcollado:i have already added `mv`!!

Comment: @VineetMenon Yes, you're right, I didn't see that `mv` was already in the list. Anyway, my point was that, as far as I know, there isn't any `ren` command (unless you've got an alias or something set).

Comment: @jcollado:haha...that was my alias for `rename`... :D

Comment: see due to my inability to recognize that this copies the *contents* of a folder and not the actual folder itself, I had to completely nuke 2 of my Node.js projects :D

Answer (score 28):

If you want to copy directory please use below command:

```
sudo cp -R Source_Folder Destination_Folder
```

This command can also be used to copy files, by just removing the "-R" which is used to copy the recursive structure of internal folders (if there are any in the Source_Folder path that we mentioned.)

One more example:

```
sudo cp -R /var/www/* /home/test_user/
```

Please feel free to leave a comment in case of any issue.

Comment: Why does `user1@server: sudo cp -r /home/user1/foo/* /home/user2/foo/` return `permission denied` when I added it to sudoers file? I am so confused.. visudo: `user1 ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/cp  -r /home/user1/foo/* /home/user2/foo/`?

Answer (score 8):

For copy folder via terminal, you can use:

```
cp -a /source/. /dest/
```

The `-a` option is an improved recursive option. It preserves all file attributes and also preserves symlinks.

The `.` at the end of the source path is a specific cp syntax that allows copying all files and folders, including hidden ones.

An alternative is `rsync`:

```
rsync -r source/ destination
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the better way is to use `gksu nautilus` command and you can copy whatever you want with common GUI as usual.

Comment: That assumes you are using a GUI and not CLI.