# Move file to external hard drive sub-directory

Tags: 16.04, usb, mount, hard-drive

I am looking to copy a file from a sub-directory on my Ubuntu 16.04 system to an external USB drive ([this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0010YWPZ8)) using the CLI. The drive has the following file and folder structure:

```
/Backup
/Backup/Jan_02_2016
/Backup/Jun_02_2016
robert_11042016.pdf
pre_install_15102014.pdf
Magazine_2012.pdf
```

I need to create a new sub-directory named `/Backup/Dec_02_2016`. Then I need to copy `/home/User_F_Readout/Downloads/Temp_Report_56_09242016.txt` to a new sub-directory `/Backup/Dec_02_2016` on the usb drive.

Previously, I have only copied files to the main directory of the external drive, so I did not need to create sub-directories - I would just mount the drive with

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/usb
```

and then just copy the file to `/mnt/usb`. This would place the file in the main directory of the external USB drive and then I could unmount.

**Problem:**

Here, the problem I am facing is that I now need to place the file in the subdirectory `/Backup/Dec_02_2016` and not in the main directory of the drive. I had a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/668261/copy-files-from-internal-hard-drive-to-external-hard-drive-using-command-line-in) but it does not indicate how to mount the drive to a mount point with the proper sub-directory structure.

**Question:**

Is there a way to place this file directly in the sub-directory? Or do I need to place it in the main directory and then move it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Mount the device** as `/mnt/usb`
2. **Create a folder**

   ```
   mkdir -p  /mnt/usb/Backup/Dec_02_2016
   ```
3. **Copy** to the recently mounted device

   ```
   cp -p /home/User_F_Readout/Downloads/Temp_Report_56_09242016.txt /mnt/usb/Backup/Dec_02_2016
   ```

Comment: Thanks! Why did you use `cp -p` instead of `cp`?

Comment: That way it preserves the specified attributes of the original files, in case there is any.

Comment: Thanks. Then should we always use `cp -p`? i.e. is `cp -p` safer than `cp`?

Comment: Only if you intend to keep all existing permissions. Not always desirable if you're copy files to a drive you might move to a different machine (with different users and groups)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use move command and set path of hard disk.

```
sudo mv fromPath/ /media/username/harddisk name/
```

Thanks.