# Failed upgrade to 17.10; can I copy /home contents to external drive before re-install?

Tags: boot, upgrade, backup, 17.10

The upgrade failed, but I was planning to re-install anyways because I kept getting error messages with compiz and unity, with occasional crashes + bugs (see my other posts + some).

I can easily access grub and the recovery menu, as well as a live USB, so I can only use those three paths to access my data.

If it's easier to repair the current installation; then there are two lines in the sequence that fail, but they go by so fast I can't read what they are. I will find out what they are if necessary though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy files from internal hard drive to external hard drive using command line in ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/668261/copy-files-from-internal-hard-drive-to-external-hard-drive-using-command-line-in)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but it would not be wise as you seem to have compiz and unity problems as well and these could be profile- or system-related, so the safest bet is to:

```
cp --recursive --preserve=timestamps /home/szYourUser /media/backup/szYourUser
```

reinstall and copy only your documents, videos, music, ... folders back and be done with it.

For important individual applications, you can restore individual hidden config files, but I would definitely not restore the entire `/home` unless you know exactly where the trouble is coming from and exclude those config files...

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I have unfortunately already done a full reinstall, but without any of the previous programs, although the folders and data for them were moved over as well... I will create a new post regarding this specific issue I have created in the future to see how I can remove the ones I don't need.   Thanks!   >and be done with it.  Literally my favourite string of words.